# Applying query filters to JavaScript array of objects

Tags: javascript

```
const sample_table1_data = [
    { title: 'aa-1', customers: ['a', 'b']},
    { title: 'aa-2', customers: ['a', 'c']},
    { title: 'bb-1', customers: ['d', 'e']},
    { title: 'cc-1', customers: ['b', 'e', 'f']},
    { title: 'dd-1', customers: ['f', 'g']},
    { title: 'dd-2', customers: ['g']},

]
```

I am trying to filter the array of objects that looks like above.
Let's say I give queries for both `title` which is a string and `customer` which is an array of strings.

I made a function named `filterData` which takes an object that looks like

```
let filter_info = {
    title: ['aa, cc'], customer: ['b']
}
```

I want the function to filter out the objects that have `aa` in the `title` and `b` in the `customers`, expecting the output to be

```
output = [
    { title: 'aa-1', customers: ['a', 'b']},
    { title: 'cc-1', customers: ['b', 'e', 'f']},
]
```

because these are the two objects that satisfy the queries (title that includes aa and cc AND customers include 'b')

I tried

```
filterData = (filters) => {
    let title_filter = filters.title
    let customer_filter = filters.customer
    const myItems = this.state.table1_data

    const keywordsToFindLower = title_filter.map(s => s.toLowerCase());
    const customerKeywords = customer_filter.map(s => s.toLowerCase())

    // filters the profile data based on the input query (selected option)
    const newArray = myItems.filter(item =>
        keywordsToFindLower.some(
            title_filter => (item.title.toLowerCase()).includes(title_filter)
        ) 
        &&
        customerKeywords.some(
            customer_filter => (item.customers.toLowerCase()).includes(customer_filter)
        ) 
    )
}
```

However, this gives me an error since `customers` is an array, not a string.

What is the correct usage if I want to achieve this task?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are almost there. You can use [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) on customers array in the filter method like this:

```
item.customers.some(value => value.toLowerCase().includes(customer_filter))
```

Then your filter method would look like:

```
const newArray = myItems.filter(item =>
        keywordsToFindLower.some(
            title_filter => (item.title.toLowerCase()).includes(title_filter)
        ) 
        &&
        customerKeywords.some(
            customer_filter =>
              (item.customers.some(
                 value => value.toLowerCase().includes(customer_filter))
              )
        ) 
    )
```